How to typeset such table?
I want to typeset this table in latex:

I tried to use combination of \multicolumn and \multirow and \diagbox but without any success. How to typeset this table in array environment preferably with some packages without custom commands?
I came up with this code:
    \begin{array}{|lr|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline & B & B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 & B_5 \\
        \cline { 3 - 7 } A & & 50 & 10 & 65 & 25 & 10 \\
        \hline A_1 & 40 & 8 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
        \hline A_2 & 60 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 8 \\
        \hline A_3 & 70 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 5 \\
        \hline A_4 & 35 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 2 \\
        \hline
    \end{array}

which produces the

but I can't put the \diagbox in there. What to do?

On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Here is a solution with {NiceArray} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|lr|l|l|l|l|l|}[hlines]
 \Block{2-2}{} & B & B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 & B_5 \\
  A & & 50 & 10 & 65 & 25 & 10 \\
  A_1 & 40 & 8 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
  A_2 & 60 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 8 \\
  A_3 & 70 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 5 \\
  A_4 & 35 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 2 \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (1-|1) -- (3-|3) ; 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}


nicematrix also provides its own command \diagbox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|lr|l|l|l|l|l|}[hlines]
 \Block{2-2}{\diagbox{A}{B}} & & B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 & B_5 \\
      &    & 50 & 10 & 65 & 25 & 10 \\
  A_1 & 40 & 8 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
  A_2 & 60 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 8 \\
  A_3 & 70 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 5 \\
  A_4 & 35 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 2 \\
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}


It's also possible to use \diagbox to draw the line and put the labels A and B as usual.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|lr|l|l|l|l|l|}[hlines]
 \Block{2-2}{\diagbox{\relax}{\relax}} & B & B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 & B_5 \\
  A & & 50 & 10 & 65 & 25 & 10 \\
  A_1 & 40 & 8 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
  A_2 & 60 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 8 \\
  A_3 & 70 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 5 \\
  A_4 & 35 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 2 \\
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}



Banishing the lone letters into the far bottom-left and top-right corners doesn't do much for the readability. Is there a way to place "A" vertically above the "A_x" terms and to place "B" on the same horizontal line with the "B_x" terms?

Out of all answers this is most visually similar to desired result. Thank You! I will read texdoc about nicematrix to get started.

@Mico: Good question. I have added a third part to my answer, which shows that it's possible to use \diagbox with empty arguments and put the labels A and B as usual.

Thanks, this change makes the table look a lot better. Really.

I've never found tables that contain big diagonal lines to be easy to understand. Providing more structure to the header rows and columns is almost always a better way to go. Question: Are your readers supposed to "know" what A and B denotes? If the answer isn't a resolute "yes", you may want to indulge your readers by being a little bit less terse.
Oh, and giving the table a more open and inviting "look", by getting rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules, definitely improves the chances that your readers will actually take the time to study the table's contents.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules (\toprule, etc.)
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{A} & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{B} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-7}
& & B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 & B_5 \\ 
& & 50  & 10  & 65  & 25  & 10  \\
\midrule
A_1 & 40 & 8 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
A_2 & 60 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 8 \\
A_3 & 70 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 5 \\
A_4 & 35 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}

\end{document}


And I actually would use $A_1=40$, $B_1=50 and so on. I'd probably also remove the “A” and “B” headers that are implicit in the names of the variables.

@egreg - These are some very good suggestions. :-) Removing the "A" and "B" headers should be a must, for sure. I must confess that I'm still in grave doubt over what many (all, in fact) of the table's elements might mean. Definitely not my favorite layout.

I think I'd be in favor of Mico's placement of $A$ and $B$, but @egreg's observation that the subscripts should be removed (and eliminate that row and column).  But that depends on what $A$ and $B$ actually mean.

Your mileage may vary, but I believe you can get rid of several things in the table.
A caption explaining what A and B refer to is needed. The explanation is courtesy of Lewis Carroll.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

$\begin{array}{@{} *6{c} @{}}
\toprule
& B=50 & B=10 & B=65 & B=25 & B=10 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
A=40 & 8 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
A=60 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 8 \\
A=70 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 7 & 5 \\
A=35 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$

\caption{Output of the gimbling operation for different
  values of $A$ (borogoves) and $B$ (toves); it is
  assumed that the borogoves are mimsy and the toves
  are slithy}

\end{table}

\end{document}


